# System center service manager Web portal

Tags: sharepoint, service, system, center

i am going to install "System Center Service Manager Web Portal" , so there are two option 1- web content server. 2-SharePoint web part.

if i only install web content server, is it provide me web console or not ?[image]

and what is the benefit to integrate with SharePoint ?

Answer (score 0):

In Self Service Portal all his components are web parts. So if you don't install the second option you don't be able to see the Self Service Portal forms and views.